# Dynamic columns in where clause while reading parquet files in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, dynamic, pyspark

I have parquet files and want to read them based on dynamic columns, so take an example, I have 2 data frames and want to select data from df1 based on df2.

so I am using the below code but want to make it dynamic in terms of joining columns, today i have 2 columns, tomorrow i can have 4.

```
a = dict[keys]
col1 = a[0]
col2 = a[1]
v = df1.join(df2,[df1[col1] == df2[col1],
df1.[col2] == df2.[col2],
how='inner')
```

So how can i make this columns dynamic so the join condition need not be be hard coded and will add remove columns from join condition.

Answer (score 0):

I would just generation an join condition object first based on your dict and then use it in the join.

```py
from functools import reduce

join_condition = reduce(
    lambda a, b: a && b,
    [ df1[col] == df2[col] 
     for col 
     in dict[keys]
    ]
)

v = df1.join(
    df2,
    join_condition,
)
```